# Loading data to store in Vue not working when routing from URL (works when clicking on a button)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url-routing, store, vue-router

*Sorry for the somewhat clumsy wording of the question. I'm a bit uncertain how to phrase it perfectly so feel free to suggest an alteration.*

I have a menu system where clicking on a link loads data to the store (it dispatches a command for it to the store and tells it what kind of data that should be loaded to the state variables).

```
menuClick: function(event) {
  const dataKind = event.target.id;
  this.$store.dispatch("updateData", { type: dataKind });
}
```

I also have a router like this.

```
import Thing1 from "./thing1.vue";
export const routes = [
    ...,
    { path: "/stuff/thing1", component: Thing1 }
];
```

This setup works and I'm happy with it. Or, rather, I **was** happy with it until a colleague pointed out that simply typing in the URL (adding a bookmark, following a link etc., anything but the actual click on the menu item) doesn't do the trick. The page is rendered as supposed to but the data isn't loaded and so we only show the message that *no bananas...* there.

How can I resolve it?

One approach I'm considering is hooking up the dispatch of update request to the routing event and not only on clicking in the menu. The problem is that I don't know how to technically speaking. Is it possible at all?

The second approach would be loading the data not at a click in the menu (or at least not only at the click) but at a later stage. The problem with this approach is that I have no idea where to place the update. What would be a good spot?

Are there other approaches to consider?

Comment: Why you didn't handle data loading into component ? I think there is a wrong use case with dispatching.

Comment: @BelminBedak Good question. I'm fairly new to the tech so I might have done it incorrectly. I've tried to follow the suggestions on their page telling me to have an external store and dispatch updates to it so that they get save in the state. Then, I have the getters that expose the state to the component. How would you suggest to approach it?

Comment: It's hard to say, but what data are you sending to store when you trigger this `menuClick` method ?

Comment: I'm only providing an ID to the store through the dispatch method. The store then will take care of the actual ajax call to fetch the data and populate the state.

Comment: Okay, so that's a bit wrong way I think.What would I do here: First you should send that ID as route params, and then in your component, you could watch that route, and get data for specific ID in component.See how I did it here https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/blob/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app/views/PostView.vue#L56

Comment: @BelminBedak Oh, that was a few new ideas there, as I watch your code. Perhaps I can improve my architecture from a bunch of different angles at the same time. Please post this as a reply so I can accept it as an answer. Then, I'll give you a link to a question that I'll post in a few minutes so that we can create an artifact for others starting with Vue to follow. And you'll get more rep too (not that it matters, of course, nobody's here answering incompetent questions because of that, no, hahaha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [beforeMount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount) or any other [Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks), if you have to initialise some required data. You can have a method which updates the data in the store and call that same method while initialising and on menuClick.

The structure should look like following:

```
export default {
  components: { },
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateStore (value) {
      this.$store.dispatch("updateData", { type: value })
    },
    menuClick: function(event) {
      const dataKind = event.target.id
      this.updateStore( dataKind )
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    if(this.$route.dataKind && someOtherConditionIfNeeded){
      this.getDetails(this.$route.dataKind)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set that ID as route parameter, and then into component, you can watch route, and data would be collected when route is activated. (https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html)

There is an example from my repo https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/blob/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app/views/PostView.vue#L56.

For VueJS 1.x users, there is a bit different way with `data` and `route` object

```
route: {
    data ({ to }) {
      // Triggering method, and sending route params
    }
}
```